# Project Euler #16 on Python

Tags: python

```
import math

def sumOfDigit(num):
    sum_of_digits = 0
    while num > 9:
        sum_of_digits += num % 10
        num = int(num/10)
    sum_of_digits += num
    return sum_of_digits

print sumOfDigit(math.pow(2,1000))
```

This is what I thought of for `Project Euler #16`, and it works fine for smaller numbers. But when I tried 2<sup>1000</sup>, the code gave me `1289.0` instead of the answer `1366` (Found this on the internet). I think the problem might have to do with the size of the number, but I'm not sure. Any points in the right direction will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the question https://projecteuler.net/problem=16

Comment: Please include what you are trying to achieve in the question, not as an external link.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that `math.pow(2,1000)` returns a `float` and not an `int`. Therefore, the operation `num/10` returns a different answer than expected.

When calling with `2 ** 1000` the expected answer is returned.

**Edit:** in case of python 3, please note [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016514/hans) comment or [tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) answer regarding integers division.

Comment: With a Python 3.5.2, I just got the same problem even when using `2**1000` as the argument; I had to - additionally - use floor division in the reduction step to get the right result: `num = num//10`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`math.pow`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.pow) returns a floating point number, and for that large a number, the floating point precision is not good enough to give you a precise answer. Change your function like this:

```
def sumOfDigit(num):
    sum_of_digits = 0
    while num > 9:
        sum_of_digits += num % 10
        num = num // 10  # use integer division // instead of /
    sum_of_digits += num
    return sum_of_digits

print(sumOfDigit(pow(2, 1000))) # use builtin pow or ** operator instead of math.pow
```

Or shorter:

```
print(sum(int(c) for c in str(2**1000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that your number calculation is simply wrong. It can be achieved much easier:

```
import math

number = str(int(math.pow(2,1000)))
total = 0

for i in number:
    total += int(i)

print(total) #1366
```

Simply calculate the result of 2<sup>1000</sup>, convert it to `str` and go through the numbers to sum them up.

Comment: Unexpectedly, this works. I don't understand how `int(math.pow(2, 1000))` could find all the digits as `math.pow(2, 1000)` is a float. Do you have an explanation ?

Comment: @Gribouillis Might have something to do that it's a power of two and thus can be represented exactly even as a floating point number.

Comment: @tobias_k Indeed the ieee754 representation of `2**1000` on 64 bits is `0 11111100111 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. All the information is in the exponent. It is an exact number.

Comment: As Elisha notes, the problem is not strictly the floating point representation of math.pow, but the _division by 10_ in the loop which gets a wrong result on the float.

Answer (score 0):

Without math module, basically can be done like this:

```
a=list(str(2**1000))
b=0
for i in range(0,len(a)):
b+=int(a[i])
print(b)
```